# What is the minimum embedding dimension for a given graph with unit line-segments as edges?

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, algebraic-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

> For a given finite set of edges $E$, what is the minimum value of $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that the given graph can be constructed with each edge between two vertices being a unit line-segment?

**Note:** Edges are allowed to intersect other edges and vertices. But no two vertices may occupy the same point.

E.g; if $E=\{\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{c,a\}\}$, then $E$, forms an equilateral triangle $\triangle abc$, which must be embedded with these conditions in minimum $\mathbb{R}^2$.

As another example, the edges of a unit-simplex can be embedded with these conditions in at minimum  $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Beyond trivial maximum bounds like $n<|E|$, and $n<k$ for $k$ vertices, I'm unsure on how to continue.

I suppose what I'm asking if there exists some function $f(E)=n$. Also, let me know if my terminology/notation for this problem can be improved.

Comment: You can have as many edges as you want in ${\bf R}^2$. $k$ vertices in a line, with $k-1$ edges, one edge joining each pair of consecutive points, $k$ arbitrarily large. You must have some condition in mind that you aren't stating. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_distance_graph

Comment: @GerryMyerson Perhaps my question is not clear, I'm asking if for a given set of vertices, and given set of edges between those vertices, what is the minimum $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the given graph can be constructed with every edge being of unit length. I'm looking for an algorithm that takes a set of edges and returns $n$. E.g; The wire-frame graph of a cube can be constructed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the wire-frame graph of a equilateral tetrahedron must be constructed in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @user1001001 What about the case of the simplex? Such graph with unit length edges can only be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: I think that @Graviton's question might be this: Given a finite set of vertices and edges between them, for what minimum dimension $k$ is there a straight-line embedding of the edges, i.e., an embedding of a vertices so that (i) if $i, j$ is an edge, then $d(v_i, v_j) = 1$, and (ii) If we embed each edge in the obvious way (as a length-one **straight line segment** between $v_i$ and $v_j$, then no two edges intersect except at a vertex that is a vertex of each.

Comment: @JohnHughes That's correct, for some reason I had in mind that all graphs had straight edges and only used curved ones for the sake of visualization.

Comment: To put it differently, given a set $E$ of distinct pairs $(i.j)$, with $1 \le i,j \le n$, we can construct a collection of edges in $\Bbb R^n$ by first letting  $v_i = (0, \ldots, a, \ldots, 0)$, where the $a$ is in the $i$th place, and $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and then drawing the straight line (which has length $1$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$ ) in $\Bbb R^n$. This produces a geometric 1-dimensional object $G$ in $\Bbb R^n$. OP asks for the smallest $k$ such that it's possible to find a piecewise linear embedding of $G$ in $\Bbb R^k$. The number $k$ may, naturally, depend on the set $E$.

Comment: If you insist on edges intersecting only at vertices, then how do you construct the wire-frame graph of a cube in ${\bf R}^2$?

Comment: The wire-frame graph of a cube has "embedding dimension" (i.e. the thing @Graviton seeks) equal to $3$, not $2$. So you *don't* construct that!

Comment: @GerryMyerson My apologies, edge intersection is allowed.

Comment: Oh, hell. "edge intersection is allowed." Ignore my previous rewrites. I guess that what OP wants is a piecewise-linear *immersion* of the object $G$, but one that restricts to an embedding on the vertex set or something. At this point, I honestly don't know. But I'm pretty sure OP wants straight line segments of length $1$. :(

Comment: Am i allowed to embed the "square" $(A,B), (B, C), (C, D), (D, A)$ by sending $A$ and $C$ to $0$ on the number line, and $B$ and $D$ to $1$? That preserves distances, but the edges "intersect" pretty badly.

Comment: @JohnHughes I didn't mean to ignore your rewrites. As only an undergrad in math my vocabulary to express problems in the right terminology can be frustrating. Edges may intersect edges and vertices, but no two vertices may overlap.

Comment: Understood -- I was just frustrated with myself for misunderstanding. I've now written an "answer" to try to further clarify what your question might be.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A186705 tabulates "the maximum number of occurrences of the same distance among n points in the plane." E.g., the entry for $n=7$ is $12$ because with seven points you can have a graph in ${\bf R}^2$ with $12$ unit-distance edges but no more than $12$. This seems to be a hard problem; the number is only known for $1\le n\le14$, namely, $0,1,3,5 7,9,12,14,18,20,23,27,30,33$, and for $21$ points it's $57$, and for $27$ points it's $81$. So, e.g., if you have $14$ vertices and more than $33$ edges, you can't draw it as a unit-distance graph in the plane. (continued)

Comment: (continued) It says an upper bound is $\lfloor kn^{4/3}\rfloor$, "if $k$ is near enough to $1$." Some links are given to the literature, which may help illuminate the general question. The numbers for ${\bf R}^4$ are given in http://oeis.org/A144873 which claims to be a formula for all $n\ge5$, but I find it hard to believe that a complete answer is known in four dimensions when so little is known in two. Maybe I have misunderstood. Anyway, there are links there which may clarify matters. I don't see anything for ${\bf R}^3$ at OEIS.

Comment: Have you followed up on any of those links, Graviton?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have, very fascinating. It does seem that this is a PhD level question. With that in mind then I imagine the answer to my question is "no, there is no general or closed form algorithm". That being said, perhaps it's a tougher question to ask what $a(n)$ is for those two sequences over my question.

Comment: A basic upper bound: we need at most $d = 2\chi(G)$ dimensions. Let $c : V \to \{1, \dots, \chi(G)\}$ be a vertex coloring, let $\theta : V \to [0, 2\pi)$ be injective, and let $e_1, \dots, e_d$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then $f : V \to \mathbb{R}^d$ given by $f(v) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\cos(\theta(v))e_{2c(v)-1} + \sin(\theta(v))e_{2c(v)})$ has the desired properties, and none of the edges cross.

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer, but too long for comments**

I think that the question might be this:

You're given a set $$ of distinct pairs $(, )$, with $1 \le i, j \le n$, and with all the numbers $1,\ldots, n$ appearing in either the first or second entry of some item in $E$. [This condition means you can't be given $(4, 5)$, $(5, 6)$, $(6, 4)$, or at least that if you ARE given that, you should rewrite it as $(1,2), (2, 3), (3, 1)$.]

Let $v_i$ denote $(0, \ldots, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \ldots, 0$, where the nonzero entry is at location $i$.

Construct a collection $G(E)$ of line segments in $\Bbb R^n$ associated to $E$ by including in $G$ the unit-length segment from $v_i$ to $v_j$ if and only if $(i,j) \in E$.

A function $f$ sending each point $v_i$ to a point $p_i = f(v_i) \in \Bbb R^k$ can be extended, piecewise linearly, to a function $\bar{f}$ on $G(E)$. The image $\bar{f}(G(E))$ looks like a "connect-the-dots" version of $G(E)$ in $R^k$. If $f$ has the property that $d(p_i, p_j) = 1$ whenever $(i,j) \in E$, we can say that $f$ "preserves lengths".

Equivalently, and perhaps more simply (avoiding the explicit construction of the set $G(E)$ which "looks" like the graph defined by $E$, we can say this.

Again, given $E$ as above, a map $f:\{1, \ldots n\} \to \Bbb R^k$ is "nice for $E$" if

1. it's injective, and
2. for all $(i, j) \in E$, we have $d(f(i), f(j)) = 1$.

The idea here is that letting $P_i = f(i)$, and drawing in the straight-line segments from $P_i$ to $P_j$, for every $(i,j) \in E$, we get the kind of picture that OP was thinking of.

The question is then, "Given $E$, what's the smallest dimension $k$ such that there's a map $f: \{1, \ldots, n\} \to \Bbb R^k$ that's nice for $E$?"

I still worry, however, that the OP really probably wants to restrict to maps for which the edges of $E$ meet only transversely. In particular, the two adjacent squares at the top of the following diagram define a set of unit-length edges $E$. The second drawing, below, shows a positioning of the 6 dots in a way that's "nice for $E$", but may not be what OP is looking for, because two of the vertical edges of the shape "overlap a lot", even though all six vertices are distinct.
[image]

Either way (whether this last example is good or not), I think that perhaps what OP needs to search for is something like "graphs and **rigidity**", but I could be misremembering what it's actually called.

Comment: I appreciate this clarification, very insightful. Thank you, this is exactly my question. I also do not mind if the edge's meet transversely, both images would satisfy my conditions. As for what I can gather about rigidity, such a graph embedding would optimize the rigidity (or lessen the degrees of freedom of the "joints").

Comment: OK, Good. I wish I actually knew the ANSWER to your question, although @GerryMyerson's comments suggest that it may be rather challenging, even if you restrict your questions to the case where the graph is the complete graph on $n$ nodes.